# Real time visualization in AWS

Tags: aws

I want to improve my current application. I am using redis using ElastiCache in AWS in order to store some user data from my website.

This solution is not scalable and I want to scale it using Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose for the autoscale streaming output, AWS Lambda to modify the output of my logs.

I want to visualise  the data in near real time and here is where my doubt is:

If I use s3 to store my straming data and I use aws athena and a use a web-based applications for visualise this data in near real time, aws is going to charge me every time that the application will update the new log data?

A best solution could be use AWS elastic search and do it with Kibana?